# spark scan hbase: scan columns reduce the efficiency?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase

Today, I use spark to scan Hbase. My Hbase has a column family named "cf", and there are 25 columns in "cf". I want to scan onf of the columns, for example : column8. So I set Hbase conf:

```
val myConf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
 myConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "compute000,compute001,compute002")
     myConf.set("hbase.master", "10.10.10.10:60000")
     myConf.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181")
     myConf.set("hbase.defaults.for.version.skip", "true")
     myConf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, table)
     myConf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMNS, "cf:column8")
     val hbaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(myConf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
            classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
            classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])
     val newHbaseRDD = hbaseRDD.map { case (_, result) =>
              Array( Bytes.toString(result.getValue(cf.getBytes, i.getBytes)).toDouble)
            }

          newHbaseRDD  //Array[Double]
```

it takes me **30 min**, however, **if I don't set SCAN_COLUMNS** ,it only takes me **4 min**.

What's wrong, shouldn't I set the parameter 'SCAN_COLUMNS'?

Can you help me, thx a lot.

---

### update

```
    val scanColumn = "cf:auth_fail_numbers cf:auth_numbers cf:cpu_use_rate"+
  " cf:harddisk_use_rate cf:http_req_fail_num cf:http_req_num cf:memory_use_rate" +
  " cf:multi_abend_numbers cf:multi_fail_numbers cf:multi_req_numbers" +
  " cf:vod_fail_numbers cf:vod_req_numbers"
  myConf.set(TableInputFormat.SCAN_COLUMNS, scanColumn)
```

when I use this code, put some columns to scan, the application causes an error:

```
     ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 22 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times; 
aborting job
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 22 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, 
most recent failure: Lost task 22.3 in stage 0.0 (TID 234, compute031): java.lang.NullPointerException
    at no1.no1$$anonfun$9.apply(no1.scala:137)
    at no1.no1$$anonfun$9.apply(no1.scala:137)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler
$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried some examples, but it does not show any difference to me. But, i would suggest one thing, submit your spark-submit job with debug mode, i mean update your log4.properties in (<SPARK_HOME>/conf), to DEBUG level. If it does not existing, copy from the .template file already there is and make sure you see debug messages. Then, check the job once, if it gives any clues.

Comment: I am currently working on Hbase and spark environment, so lets see, where it takes. and, whats the size of your table.? how many column families and how many columns.?